# What is the minimum degree for a curve that has two different points.

Tags: polynomials

I'm having some difficulty solving this problem. The information I have is the following:

What is the minimum degree for a curve that has two different points.( 2 different ordered pairs let s say (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow a few guidelines.  In particular, make sure your question is clear. What do you mean by "a curve that has two different points"? Do you mean two different ordered pairs in the curve, or two different values of $y$, or what?

Answer (score 1):

One might think the minimum degree is $1$ since given two points $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ with $a \neq c$ there is a line $y=mx+b$ through the two points. But the polynomial $mx+b$ has degree $1$ only provided $m \neq 0.$ Now it would depend on how the problem is interpreted. If it means what is the minimal degree which would work for *all* choices of two points (with different $x$ coordinates), then the answer is $1$ as mentioned. But if the question means to find the minimal degree which *could* occur for the two points, then the answer is $0$, since e.g. for the points $(2,5)$ and $(4,5)$ the line equation becomes $y=5,$ where the degree of the constant polynomial $5$ is zero.

Comment: let s say it s not a line, it s a curve or can we consider a line as a curve? and i also had a question after that asking for the minimum degree of the slope so i assumed it s the derivative of the curve so 1 degree less is that correct?

Comment: @JoeSleiman Most mathematical definitions consider a line as a special case of a curve. True, in common language the term "curve" would imply its being bent somewhat. (For that one would need degree at least 2.) I've never heard of the "degree of the slope" unless it means the degree of the derivative.

Comment: okay, thank you for your explanation it was very useful but I need one more favor if possible: in the case where the curve is bent and the degree is 2, can you explain how did we prove that the minimum degree is 2 please?

Comment: @JoeSleiman The only possible degree zero or one polynomials are those of the form $a\cdot x + b,$ which has degree zero if $m=0$ and degree $1$ if $a \neq 0.$ [Technically the zero polynomial $0$ is not said to even have a degree.] If we use $a=m$ we get the usual $y=mx+b$ format used above. So degree *less* than 2 implies a line. Thus we need degree *at least* 2 to get a curve which is bent, such as $y=2x^2+3x-7.$